# What happens when you apply a margin to a CSS percentage?

Tags: css

Say I have the following:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
<div style="height:80%;margin-top:10px;">test</div>
```

As I resize the screen, it maintains the 80% ratio to a certain point, then it breaks and stops being 80% of the height of the screen. What exactly is going on behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1):

That's a relatively complex issue called "box-sizing".

There a fantastic read about it that will answer you question on css-tricks: http://css-tricks.com/international-box-sizing-awareness-day/

In essence, what is happening in your case, is that the margin-top takes precedence. When you have 50 pixels total height, 10 get removed and 80% of 50 would be 40 - just enough. Make it any smaller and the 80% will instead be "everything thats left"

Answer (score 0):

If you use %, you must set a minimum size.

Example width: 80%; min-width: 1200px;

When you zoom or less than 1200px screen, it fixes the elements and 1200px, not breaking the screen like this happening to you.

Hope this helps =D

Comment: The OP is talking about height.

Answer (score 0):

1. ```
   html { height: 100%; }
   ```

   makes `<html>` have full window height.
2. ```
    body { height: 100%; }
   ```

   makes `<body>` have 100% height of `<html>`. Note some browsers use

   ```
   body { margin: 8px; }
   ```

   in its default stylesheet, so `<body>` will overflow window, because those margin is not included in `height: 100%`.
3. ```
   div { height:80%; margin-top:10px; }
   ```

   makes `<div>` have 80% height of `<html>`, and adds `10px` of top margin (additional to the height).

---

If you want those `10px` to be included in `80%`, you can use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```
div { height:calc(80%-10px); margin-top:10px; }
```

or use [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) with `padding` instead of `margin`:

```
div { height:80%; padding-top:10px; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Comment: I'd add that even without `body{margin:8px}`, the `<body>` will overflow due to is original margin in most browsers.

Comment: @Zakariadza That's what I say: `body { margin: 8px; }` is the default margin for `<body>`(in Firefox).

Comment: oops, I haven't noticed that sentence :)